# add prefix to cases in php

Tags: php, passwords, generator, prefix

This is a php password generator

```
function passwdgen($strength,$length) {
    switch($strength) {
        case 'Numeric':
            $characters = '0123456789';
            break;
        case 'Lowercase Alphabetic':
            $characters = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz';
            break;
        case 'Uppercase Alphabetic':
            $characters = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
            break;
        case 'Num LC':
            $characters = '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz';
            break;
        case 'Num UC':
            $characters = '0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
            break;
        case 'LC UC':
            $characters = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
            break;
        case 'Num LC UC':
            $characters = '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
            break;
    }
    $string = '';    
    for($i = 0 ; $i < $length ; $i++) {
        $string .= $characters[mt_rand(0,strlen($characters))];
    }
    return $string;
  }
```

I would like to add static text to cases.

For example: for Numeric : text5483, or in Num LC : text242sad etc.

but I don't what to achieve this.

Comment: How are you echoing it/using this?

Comment: this is a whmcs module , you can download it from here http://kingvpn138.com/ibsng.zip

Comment: It's hard for me to say for sure, but try doing `$string .= "text" . $characters[mt_rand(0,strlen($characters))];` see if that works for you.

Comment: output : text0text7text8text8

Comment: I had a feeling it would do that; was worth a shot. I take it you want the generated string entered in DB?

Comment: and btw i wanna add different texts to each case ...

Comment: You could probably use a 3rd parameter to your function `function passwdgen($text,$strength,$length)` then assign `$text = "text";` and put that under each case. Yet, if you were to concatenate the text to the variable being entered in DB, that could work. As for different texts to each case, that I couldn't say. I remember trying something similar in the past but had too much of a hard time with, so I gave up. I will vote up, see if anyone else will pick up on it.

Comment: You're welcome. However, I could help you out better if you had a shortened version of an echo'ed output and how it's used. I spent a bit time trying to figure out how to echo a string from the generated function. If you can, let me know how you're accessing each case also.

Comment: solved :) just added a text input to module ($passprefix) , and changed this line : function passwdgen($passprefix,$strength,$length) , and this one too : return $passprefix . $string;

Comment: Great and that's kind of what I had thought of afterwards.